# Merge two data frames to get alternate rows of each data frame in sequence

Tags: r, merge

My data.frame `DATA` is

```
  k    l   g
1 A 2004  12
2 B 2004 3.4
3 C 2004 4.5
```

Another data.frame `DATA2` is

```
  i    d   t
1 A 2012  22
2 B 2012 4.8
3 C 2012 5.6
```

I want to get

```
1 A 2004  12
1 A 2012  22
2 B 2004 3.4
2 B 2012 4.8
3 C 2004 4.5
3 C 2012 5.6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can try `rbindlist` from `data.table`.  Place the datasets in a `list`, `rbind` them with `rbindlist` and `order` by the first column.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[order(k)]
#   k    l    g
#1: A 2004 12.0
#2: A 2012 22.0
#3: B 2004  3.4
#4: B 2012  4.8
#5: C 2004  4.5
#6: C 2012  5.6
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, setNames(df2, names(df1))) %>% 
           arrange(k)
```

NOTE: I used `df1` and `df2` in place of `DATA` and `DATA2` as object names as it is easier to type.

Comment: Would this still work if dataframes have different colnames?

Comment: @A.M.G16 Why did you unaccept my answer? I think my solution works just as well the dplyr one.

Comment: @h3rm4n Your solution is just similar to the one I showed with `rbindlist` (original idea)

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the `rbind` function was developed before the `rbindlist` function. You don't have to be so protective (refering to original idea), as both concepts already exist for quite some time. And I think it is legitimate to ask why someone unaccepted an answer. I am trying to learn something here and therefore like to know whether there is something wrong in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the `interleave` function from the "gdata" package. However, this would require your inputs have the same column names and have the same number of rows.

The approach would be:

```
library(gdata)      # for interleave
do.call(interleave, lapply(list(df1, df2), setNames, paste0("V", 1:ncol(df1))))
#    V1   V2   V3
# 1   A 2004 12.0
# 11  A 2012 22.0
# 2   B 2004  3.4
# 21  B 2012  4.8
# 3   C 2004  4.5
# 31  C 2012  5.6
```

Alternatively, as mentioned in my comment @akrun's answer, depending on whether the first column is a grouping variable or not, you may want to modify his approach a little.

For instance, imagine there were a third `data.frame`, with a different number of rows than the others. `interleave` would not work on that, but the `rbindlist` approach would.

```
df3 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list(df1, df2), setNames, c("A", "B", "Z")))

rbindlist(list(df1, df2, df3), idcol = TRUE)[, N := sequence(.N), by = .id][order(N)]
#     .id k    l    g N
#  1:   1 A 2004 12.0 1
#  2:   2 A 2012 22.0 1
#  3:   3 A 2004 12.0 1
#  4:   1 B 2004  3.4 2
#  5:   2 B 2012  4.8 2
#  6:   3 B 2004  3.4 2
#  7:   1 C 2004  4.5 3
#  8:   2 C 2012  5.6 3
#  9:   3 C 2004  4.5 3
# 10:   3 A 2012 22.0 4
# 11:   3 B 2012  4.8 5
# 12:   3 C 2012  5.6 6
```

Pay specific attention to the last three rows in comparison with @akrun's approach.

---

The equivalent in base R for that last "data.table" approach would be something like:

```
x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(c("df1", "df2", "df3"), function(x) {
  setNames(cbind(rn = x, get(x)), c("id", paste0("V", 1:ncol(get(x)))))
}))
x[order(ave(as.numeric(x$id), x$id, FUN = seq_along)), ]
```

<sub>*(So the moral is, use "data.table".)*</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this in base R with `rbind` without the need to use extra packages, but you will have to set the columnnames of `df2` the same as the columnnames in `df1`:

```
colnames(df2) <- colnames(df1) # or: setNames(df2, colnames(df1))
new.df <- rbind(df1,df2)
new.df <- new.df[order(new.df$k),]
```

This will result in the following dataframe:

```
> new.df
   k    l    g
1  A 2004 12.0
11 A 2012 22.0
2  B 2004  3.4
21 B 2012  4.8
3  C 2004  4.5
31 C 2012  5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `dplyr` without the need for a key column and without modifying the original order (if the data frames weren't sorted by an "id" column).

```
library(dplyr)

stopifnot((N <- nrow(DATA)) == nrow(DATA2))

INTER_DATA <- setNames(DATA2, names(DATA)) %>%
    bind_rows(DATA, .) %>%
    arrange(rep(seq_len(N), length = n()))
```

Result:

```
  k    l    g
1 A 2004 12.0
2 A 2012 22.0
3 B 2004  3.4
4 B 2012  4.8
5 C 2004  4.5
6 C 2012  5.6
```