# Scraping multiple domains at once in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have 6 sitemaps from my competitors' websites.
All combined amount to >80k pages so if I were to do it domain after domain with 5sec pause after each request it would take me ~5.5 days.

How can I scrape those 6 websites parallelly in R and keep the 5sec pause for each website separately to make no harm to their performance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whether you do it in parallell or not, you are committed to only one request to each domain every 5 seconds. Should you not just send a request to each domain in a cyclical fashion, say once per second?

Comment: Hm, so you say I mix those sitemaps to create one big list like: (dom1.com/a, dom2.com/a, ...., dom6.com/a, dom1.com/b, dom2.com/b,....), right? Seems like a good idea. Is there an easy way to mix rows from several dataframes this way? EDIT: Nvm, found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356989/merge-two-data-frames-to-get-alternate-rows-of-each-data-frame-in-sequence

Comment: Put the data frames in a list, then cycle through the list sending one request per data frame then sleep for 1 second. Iterate as many times as the number of rows of your longest dataframe. When the loop counter exceeds the length of your shorter data frames, keep the 1 second pause. The whole thing should be complete in about 24 hours.

Comment: I don't think you should combine the data frames like that, otherwise you need a method of mixing the rows up in the same order, and the site with the most pages will have a bunch of consecutive records at the end, so you will be sending one request per second to the same domain at the end of the data frame